# enable a link after sending a $.post on jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I'm trying to send some ajax POST before enabling the click.

I tried this:

```
$('.unread a').click(function(){
    ele = $(this);
    $.post('ajax/notification.php', {
    info : ele.attr('title')
    }, 
    function(data) {
        if(data != 'frack') {
            ele.addClass("read");
            ele.removeClass("unread");
            window.location = ele.attr("href");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

but when I click on the link, it goes directly to the page without having time to send the $.post.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just realised you're already doing `return false;` which should do the same thing as calling `preventDefault()`. Can you post the HTML that this code runs against? It's possible your selector is wrong, and therefore the event handler isn't actually being bound.

Comment: Just to make sure. And you don't have any other JS errors on this page?

Comment: There was an error at ele.attr("href") which was suppose to be ele.parents("li").attr("href"). I think it's working now :|

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent the link from sending you somewhere

```
$('.unread a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I made the same mistake, but the `return false;` in the code should do the same thing as `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

this prevents the link from doing it's default action

```
    preventDefault();
```

so

```
$('.unread a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ele = $(this);
    $.post('ajax/notification.php',
                 { info : ele.attr('title')
                    }, 
        function(data) {
        if(data != 'frack'){
                ele.addClass("read");
                ele.removeClass("unread");
                window.location = ele.attr("href");
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```